# How to scrape dynamic review content from steam using beautifulsoup and python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, steam

I am trying to scrape reviews from steam for a particular game. But steam has infinite scrolling mechanism, means reviews are generated dynamically as you scroll. Due to this I am able to scrape only one page, which has 10 reviews. But i need to scrape all the pages. Is there any way to do it using beautiful soup?

I have written code which is scraping the first page and showing results. But can't get further that. I've also tried looking for AJAX request and JS in the network panel, but found nothing which I can use.

```
def getHTML(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')

html = getHTML('https://steamcommunity.com/app/44350/reviews/? 
browsefilter=toprated&snr=1_5_100010_#scrollTop=0')

for div in html.find_all('div',{'class','apphub_CardTextContent'}):
    print(div.text.strip())
    print("\n\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

I found something in AJAX request and JS in the network panel. You'll have to deal with how to know you've reached the end.

```
import requests
import bs4
import re

url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/app/44350/homecontent/'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36'}

regex = re.compile('apphub_CardContentAuthorName')

for x in range(1, 99):
    offset = (x*10) - 10

    payload = {
    'userreviewsoffset': offset,
    'p': x,
    'workshopitemspage': x,
    'readytouseitemspage': x,
    'mtxitemspage': x,
    'itemspage': x,
    'screenshotspage': x,
    'videospage': x,
    'artpage': x,
    'allguidepage': x,
    'webguidepage': x,
    'integratedguidepage': x,
    'discussionspage': x,
    'numperpage': '10',
    'browsefilter': 'toprated',
    'browsefilter': 'toprated',
    'l': 'english',
    'appHubSubSection': '10',
    'filterLanguage': 'default',
    'searchText': '',
    'forceanon': '1'}



    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    cards = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'apphub_Card modalContentLink interactable'})
    for card in cards:
        title = card.find('div',{'class':'title'}).text
        hours = card.find('div',{'class':'hours'}).text
        content = card.find('div',{'class':'apphub_CardTextContent'}).text.strip()
        author = card.find('div',{'class':regex}).text

        print(title + '\n' + hours + '\n' + content + '\n\n' + 'Author: ' + author + '\n' + '#'*50)
```

**Output:**

```
Recommended
101.0 hrs on record
Posted: February 5, 2014
                                                                                                I really like GRID 2 and I think it's the best racing game on Steam. Just keep in mind that it's not a racing simulator like GRID. It's Need for Speed: Greatest Hits. I can see huge chunks of various NFS games put into the game nicely like Touge on the California Dixon track at night is a canyon race from Carbon, sponsor decals, body and performance mods are from Underground, circuit races strongly remind me of ProStreet. Cote d'Azur track alone reminds me of Porsche Unleashed and brings a smile to my face. Codemasters made a great arcade racing game.The graphics are gorgeous, physics is awesome in terms of car behavior, online matchmaking is great and single player campaign is fun to play and interesting to progress. AI can be easily adjusted to a desired difficulty.After some hours in-game assistant's voice became rather annoying and I turned it off along with generic soundtrack. I wish there were several assistants to choose from. DLCs certainly crippled the game. Extra tracks and cars just don't fit in properly, e. g. you can't use Ford Sierra RS500 online and nobody races on Bathurst unless you create a custom lobby and invite friends to play it. The lack of cockpit view is unfortunate. Also I wish there were Ferraris, Lamborghinis and Porsches but don't get me wrong, the game is great fun and there's a lot of cars to choose from.

Author: camXmile
##################################################
Recommended
318.7 hrs on record
Posted: June 10, 2017
                                                                                                I played this game first from a friend who shared their games to me, I just had a go at it since my favourite game is Grid Autosport thought its worth a go.My first impression was terrible I thought I will never play this game again, it was lagging and i was slow as well.But I continued on and honestly it become one of my favourites and then later on when it was on a lower price i bought it and then continued on with the dlc-s slowly, sadly there wasnt a season pass like grid autosportThis game is waay different from grid autosport, but in order to break it down to points lets go and start with the positives.Positives:- Drifting. I love drifting on this game I'm very good at it, In online sessions I beat level 99 players Im very happy with the drifting of this game- Music - Awesome music and soundtracks, i have them downloaded and on my phone- Just like Autosport in this game we have a lot of cars to race on which are collected in different tiers, from tier 1 to tier 4, and indycar and demolition derby.- Lot of Games modes more than Grid Autosport! It has modes like Touge (i cant pronounce that yet by the way :D) Overtake, and face off.Now personally Touge is my favourite and prefer it over faceoff because u dont need to complete the full race if u pull away 5 seconds or drop back 5 seconds behind ur rival of course if u drop u lose lol. Touge is usually on tight tracks around cliffs same with faceoff.....Overtake events are when u have to go against very slow ai cars which aren't racing, the point is to overtake as many of them and meanwhile score points, the points at the top are going up after an overtake and always getting smaller and smaller if ur not overtaking, a scale from 100 to 1000. if u crash or leave track it goes down automaticly to 100..Also an event type called liveroutes which are mostly on street tracks and that means the track layout keeps changing and u have to adapt, there are arrows to help you- Followers! On grid online, this is a feature which autosport doesn't have, here u can compare ur score of followers to other players, u get followers based on global challange or beating ur rival or completing an objective.- Rivals. You can race against weekly and social rivals and over 1 week perioud. whoever gets more xp will get more grid followers- Career mode. with cutscenes, Fans, (a number going up, and u will have more than 20 milion followers after 5 seasons) I think this career mode is better than Grid Autosports career, the better u perform along with ur objectives and results the  more fans u will get, and more fans unlock new tracks. I like that ur in a paddock it gives more to the feel.-Global challanges. You get 9 challanges per week more than Autosport which gives 5!! usually they are tough and annoying and require a lot of effort but its worth it. Also with the friends leaderboards u can see how u stand with ur other friends doing the challange and becoming first will give u a lot of xp.- Just like in Autosport u can edit liveries however here u can edit them in single player too.Now lets go to the meh. before the negatives.Handling.. Not realistic obviously its an arcade handling ur literally flying through corners drifting the rear end like ur doing doughnuts. its faster to drift also, its a disadvantage if u have a front wheel or 4wd, except a few ones.Custom event is connected with career. u can't drive with cars u havent unlocked in career. it meh cause on grid u can drive any car in gp mode.Now Negatives.-The most annoying and ridicolous thing for me is the CAR SELECTION ONLINE. It makes me angry. You only get 20 seconds to choose your car right before the race and the bloddy timer goes so fast... unlike ANY other game i played here ur under pressure to select ur car because for some reason you CANT SELECT IT from the menu before the raceNOW 2ND thing is connected to this which is EVEN MORE ANNOYING. When u join a custom event and ur the middle of championship lets say its event 2 and you're waiting for event 3... What's wrong?? It puts you straight into the event WITHOUT GIVING YOU ANY CHOICE OF CAR SELECTION. YES REALLY. THIS IS BEYOND ME. WTF IS THIS CRAP. 7-AI - They ai in general is,ok, sort of but the AI DURING THE OVERTAKE EVENTS is a disgrace I cant stand them at all, they turn into you, they squize you like mad and then you get a collison and that removes your points, hate them with a passion, its a constant battle in global challanges.- Global challange always gives bloddy impossible things like. yeah overtake with tier 4 around a track tighter than my a$$ im not even kidding. like it just annoys me. then when i wanna pass the ai guess what? they turn into me. many restarts, many angry moments.- Sprint tracks? I don't know the name, those cliff tracks where 1 wrong moment and u literally fall into your death.. I hate those tracks.. tracks like Hong Kong or Okutama. u know...u make a small mistake and u get flipped over and flipped off. Also they're so damn long some are 10 kilometers and take 3 or 4 minutes come on I hate that, after a while just by pure boredom I lose concentration and bang. regardless even with tier1 cars I hate those tracks.. its not flipping dirt rally come on. put these tracks there.. i know its tarmac but still..- There a lot of useless cars which are rarely used.. mostly because they aren't drifty or they're crappy in general I dont see how I will use those cars unless there will be a global event which stricts it down to that 1 car. example. mclaren's in tier 3 and 4. i won't name them. This might invalidate my previous point that Im happy that there are a lot of cars but oh well..- Moneywh0ring and level limits.. In order for u to have full achivements like in other games u will need almost all dlc's, in order to unlock all cars for example online u need a dlcs. in order to play 1 track and get 2 or 3 cars  u need to spend like 7 euros. it might not be a lot but come on why couldnt u just put it in the full game?  Level limits. So just because ur not a level 25 or something u cant upgrade a car  from like tier 3 to 4. so until then everyone else will use caterham in tier 4 for overtake events for example meanwhile u have to use something else, why cant u just make it more expensive why need to level up that much for that.. now this might sound a bit like crying but its unfair kind of, but its debateable it might not be. anyway that's my thoughts- small thing, Indycar is slower than Pagani Zonda Revolucion??? indycar can do 452 in grid autosport but here its slower than 370 and u can't even upgrade it, and why is Zonda 376 with 7 gears when its 6 gears on autosport?- no upgrades for DLC veichles.. -no driving line or assists- No time trial,- NO global leaderboards on racenet ingame, u have to go out there manually to codies site all the time, and u cant go through the list of people only ones who are near you.Overall I would give this 8/10 and Autosport 9/10I personally prefer Autosport but this game the way it is, is fun too except the annoying things. Why autosport? 3 reasons. handling, multiplayer and smoother fps.To all friends who have autosport, go and try Grid 2 as well pls. thanks for reading. Goodbye.

Author: LuckyRacer99
##################################################
Recommended
3.2 hrs on record
Posted: March 14
Product received for free
Free on Humble Bundle![www.humblebundle.com]

Author: Makk0
##################################################
Recommended
1.4 hrs on record
Posted: April 23
Product received for free
                                                                                                Got it free, and it runs on my Intel HD2500 graphics PC. So, if you're looking for a racing game that runs decently on a piece of trash computer, this one is probably it.

Author: Aaron

....
```